# 'undefined' object using MongoDB + Express

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, http, undefined

When I print client-side the received object on console using `console.log(this.data)`, I get `undefined`, so I cannot access `data.body` to print the data stored on the database. 
Printing server-side gets the correct json object.

I'm sending the object using HTTP status 200. Forcing a Bad Request (`res.status(400).json(docs);`) will print correctly the json body inside an Error.

client.ts

```
getEvents() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('http://www.mywebsite.com:8080/api/objects')
      .pipe(map(data => { })).subscribe(data => {
          this.data = data;
          console.log(this.data);
      });
    });   
}
```

server.js

```
app.get("/api/objects", function (req, res) {
    db.collection(COLLECTION).find({})
    .toArray(function (err, docs) {
      if (err) {
        handleError(res, err.message, "Failed.");
      } else {
        console.log(docs);
        res.status(200).json(docs);
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using some kind of body-parser, as the body-parser or express.json():

```
app.use(express.json())
```

Put that before your routes!

Comment: I can confirm using app.use(bodyParser.json()); at the beginning of the code